# Why is the IS_NULLABLE field in INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS a VARCHAR, rather than a BIT?

Tags: sql-server, types, sqldatatypes

Just to feed my curiosity:

When you look at the structure of the table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS` on SQL Server, you can see that the column `IS_NULLABLE` looks like below :

```
/-------------------------------------------\
| Column_name |   Type  | Computed | Length |
|-------------+---------+----------+--------|
| IS_NULLABLE | varchar |    no    |    3   |
\-------------------------------------------/
```

In my mind, when you want to store a boolean, the best data type to use is `BIT`.

So why have the SQL Server developers used a `VARCHAR` to store a boolean value?

Is the reason historical? Maybe the `BIT` data type didn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, they didn't have [much choice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx):

> The information schema views included in SQL Server comply with the ISO standard definition for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

That is, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are [standardized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) across SQL products - they weren't invented solely for SQL Server (this is also why they don't contain a lot of information that is product specific)

In addition, these views were standardized well *before* an actual boolean data type was added to the [SQL Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#SQL) (INFORMATON_SCHEMA exists at least as far back as the 1992 standard. Boolean was added as an optional data type in the 1999 standard). Note that `bit` isn't really a boolean data type (and it's non-standard) - it's defined in the documentation as a numeric type instead.

Comment: I wasn't so far. :) Thank you for this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the covers,`Information_schema.columns` is getting data from `sys.columns` ,you can see the same using

> EXEC sp_helptext [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS]

In `Sys.columns`,they have used `Is_nullable` column as `BIT`,but in `[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS]` ,they have generalized it like below

```
convert(varchar(3), CASE c.is_nullable
WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END)    AS IS_NULLABLE
```

As per my understanding,They might have generalized the info,rather then just showing 1 or 0 in this view..

Look out this question as well,in knowing differences between these two views

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72742/why-do-sys-columns-and-information-schema-columns-display-different-number-of-co

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, and that is a VIEW (not a TABLE), intended to give human-readable information.

The column `IS_NULLABLE` in this view returns YES or NO, which to must humans is more readable than the underlying 1 and 0 values.

Furthermore there is an ANSI standard governing `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.*` and according to that standard, YES and NO must be shown.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.